# How to store new numbers into array from data file with multiple columns

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, data-files

I am trying to store this data from this file into multiple arrays. The data file has 3 columns that are separated by a comma. When I print the arrays they just show the last number of the data file. I am lost on how to fix this. Please help! I need the 3rd number from each line stored in an array. And I also would like to learn how to store the 1st and 2nd numbers from each line in that data file into a multidimensional array, if anyone could help with that, too. This is my code so far:

```
  public static final String SOLD_HOUSES_DATA = "westcoast.txt"; 
  public static void main(String[] args)throws 
FileNotFoundException{
     File data = new File(SOLD_HOUSES_DATA);
  Scanner houseData = new Scanner(data);
  String[] housesData =null;
  int totalHouses = 0;
  int houseSQFT = 0;
  int bedroomSize = 0;
  int housePrice = 0;
  double[] o = null; 
  while (houseData.hasNextLine()){
     totalHouses++;
     housesData = houseData.nextLine().split(",");
     houseSQFT = Integer.parseInt(housesData[0]);
     bedroomSize = Integer.parseInt(housesData[1]);
     housePrice = Integer.parseInt(housesData[2]);
     o = yMatrix(totalHouses, housePrice);
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(housesData));  
     double a = normalizeHouseData(houseSQFT);
     double b = normalizeBedRoomData(bedroomSize);  
     double[][] oo = xMatrix(a, b, totalHouses);  
  }


  double a = normalizeHouseData(houseSQFT);
  double b = normalizeBedRoomData(bedroomSize);  
  double[][] oo = xMatrix(a, b, totalHouses);

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(o));



 }
```

Also, I am not able to use arrayLists for this assignment even though I know it would make things so much easier. Thanks again!

Comment: What are the different output arrays where the data should end up?

Comment: `o = yMatrix` re-assigns `o` each time. It does not append to it. What does `yMatrix` return?

Comment: yMatrix will return an array of all the numbers in the 3rd column

Comment: `o = yMatrix(totalHouses, housePrice);` this line always replace the first store values by current row values. that's why you get only last row, when you print the `o` array.
`o[totalHouses-1] = yMatrix(totalHouses, housePrice);` try like this then it should store all row values.

Comment: I can't convert a double array into a double, that's what it would be doing

Answer (score 0):

Since you are forced to use Arrays, I think your best option here is to read through the file once to count how many lines there are. Then read through a 2nd time to get the data.

```
File data = new File(SOLD_HOUSES_DATA);
Scanner houseData = new Scanner(data);
int totalHouses = 0;
// Count the lines
while (houseData.hasNextLine()){
    totalHouses++;
    // Forgot this line
    houseData.nextLine();
}
// Allocate array
double[] o = new double[totalHouses]; 
// Close and re-open the scanner to reset it
houseData.close();
houseData = new Scanner(data);
// Read through the file a 2nd time
int lineNumber = 0;
while (houseData.hasNextLine()) {
    // Parse the data into the array (needs error checking...)
    String lineData = houseData.nextLine().split(",");
    o[lineNumber] = Double.parseDouble(lineData[2]);
    lineNumber += 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I was unclear. I was trying to have "o" be a single array, with the house prices only.

Comment: Ok. Updated answer.